# How to remove a value of multi-valued SCIM 2.0 sub-attribute?

Tags: scim, scim2

I have a complex SCIM attribute that looks like follows:

```
"myattr1": {
  "subattr1": 5,
  "subattr2": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

I want to modify this to become

```
"myattr1": {
  "subattr1": 5,
  "subattr2": [1, 3]
}
```

How can I do this using PATCH ? Should I replace the entire sub-attribute or can I just remove the value 2 from it using PATCH ?

I know how to do this with multi-valued attributes. But I don't know how to do it for sub-attributes.

Answer (score 0):

**[EDIT: This is wrong..]**

I believe this will work:

```
PATCH /resource/id

{ "schemas":
      ["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"],
     "Operations":[
       {
        "op":"remove",
        "path":"myattr1[subattr2 eq \"2\"]"
        }
    ]
}
```

Example on path was taken from https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7644#page-33 where it mentions        "path":"members[value eq
"2819c223-7f76-453a-919d-413861904646"].displayName" as a way to target the displayName sub-attribute for the complex multi-valued group attribute "members".

The escaped quotes around 2 are necessary if it's a string - if the value is in fact an integer, they won't be necessary.

Comment: Isn't this supposed to delete the value of attribute 'myattr1' which contains a sub-attribute 'subattr2' with value 2 ?

members[value eq "2819c223-7f76-453a-919d-413861904646"].displayName would target all values of displayName and not a specific value. Right ?

Comment: I believe you are correct. My above answer is incorrect. I'm looking through the parts of 7644 on remove and replace and I can't find anything that lets you remove a specific sub-attribute value. I think you've already identified the most viable path - replacing the entire sub-attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

As per the PingIdentity documentation https://github.com/pingidentity/scim2/wiki/Working-with-SCIM-paths#the-value-sub-attribute, Simple multivalued attributes have a special implicit sub-attribute called "value".
If that is the way, your PATCH request payload should be as follows.

```
{
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"
    ],
    "Operations": [
        {
           "op": "remove",
           "path": "myattr1.subattr2[value eq \"2\"]"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, this type of patch operation is not clearly defined in RFC 7644 (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7644#section-3.5.2)

You would be able to confirm this if the question is raised in SCIM mailing list https://mailarchive.ietf.org/arch/browse/scim/